# Bosh over https using smack

Tags: https, smack

I am trying to have create Bosh connection to openfire over https. I have tried using the BoshConfiguration with hhtps argument as true. But connection times out at remote server.
Anyone has any working example of Bosh over https in smack ?

Answer (score 1):

I´ve faced the same problem. I could make the connection and login by changing JBosh library, since the HttpClient usage there does not consider a SSL Context.

I followed the approach used in http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=211 for this, with some modification in subscribe() method, returning the SSLContext and using in XLightWebSender.java init() method, like this:

```
public void init(final BOSHClientConfig session) {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        cfg = session;
        SSLContext context = null;
        try {
            context = this.subscribe();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        client = new HttpClient(context);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

PS: I´m still testing and don´t guarantee that this work-around works fine for long living connections.